# jQuery Checkbox dynamically created with checked property

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('<input>', {
    type: "checkbox",
    id: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    name: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    className: required + " " + dataType,
    attributeId: value.AttributeId,
    disabled: readOnly,
    checked: (value.AttributeValue != "0") ? "true" : "false"
}).appendTo(li);
```

I am dynamically creating a checkbox element. I need to then assign the checked property to it or not. But In the code below, it's always checked because the property is present.

Help?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a string here, use a boolean:

```
$('<input>', {
    type: "checkbox",
    id: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    name: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    className: required + " " + dataType,
    attributeId: value.AttributeId,
    disabled: readOnly,
    checked: (value.AttributeValue != "0")
}).appendTo(li);
```

`checked` is a boolean property in the DOM, so a string of any non-0 length is "truey", meaning that `"false"` is really `true`.  Instead set it directly to `true` or `false`, no strings.

Comment: That would be `checked: value.AttributeValue != "0"`, without the ternary. :)

Comment: @Tomalak - +1 - trees/forest and such :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option

```
$('<input>', {
    type: "checkbox",
    id: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    name: "checkbox" + value.AttributeName,
    className: required + " " + dataType,
    attributeId: value.AttributeId,
    disabled: readOnly,
}).attr('checked',value.AttributeValue!="0")
  .appendTo(li);
```